# How to make search engine index PDF files?

Tags: plugins, search

I'm looking for a plugin or a idea so that my WP 3.1 search engine can index PDF files. Has anyone be through that need too ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard WordPress search is pretty basic and only search the database, there are some plugins that extend the search functionality to search even more parts of the database like:

- [Search Everything](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-everything/)
- [Search Unleashed](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-unleashed/)

but they do not have the ability to search files.
There is one plugin that i know of that claims to support indexing PDF and DOC files

- [Sphider for WordPress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sphider/)
  which is  a bit outdated and i have tried before so you might want to check it out.

But **the best solution** I have used for this kind of "Job" is [**Google custom search**](http://www.google.com/cse/) 
that searchs PDFs and DOCs and is fairly easy to set up.

Comment: Ok I heard about Google Custom search but I kept it as a joker answer ;)

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SearchBlox](http://www.searchblox.com/searchblox-wordpress-plugin-now-available) which provides a plugin to connect the search server with Wordpress

Comment: Thanks so much, I haven't heard about this solution before. Great posts thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

This plugin searches inside PDF contents:

https://searchwp.com/

From the home page:

> **Index PDF content automatically**
>
> Index the PDFs within your Media library, allowing visitors to find content from those documents in your site search.

Answer (score 0):

I have found one solution. Maybe it will work for you also :

Masala Plugin : https://github.com/nanodust/masala , which actually add new post meta field while uploading any doc/pdf/ppt/txt file. It will put the file content into newly created meta field

This plugin uses :
1) Java
2) Apache Tika – really awesome
3) Search Everything plugin which is responsible for search in meta table.

Here, you need to configure :
1) Java path
2) Download latest apache tika jar and you can put into your project root folder and configure path in masala.php
4) Give the allowed file extensions.

ITS DONE !!

Comment: How can I reindex already uploaded files?